# How to access my Wamp Server on another Local Computer

Tags: php, apache, http, wamp

How can i access my local wamp server on another computer

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

i use this code in http.config file but not work

Answer (score 21):

You could simply use the `Put Online` option of your WAMP Server and you can use this current system IP address and to directly access from the other computer.

Do this on system tray

[image]

Then, you could find your IP address using typing `ipconfig` or [`whatismyip.com`](http://www.whatismyip.com) website and then access it on another system.

Comment: i do Put online but when i access my local server on another computer it will open but not display any images and stylesheet.

Comment: Did you use any absolute paths ?

Comment: i use my ip address 192.168.1.10/directory_name

Comment: Nope you should be using **relative paths** and you will get working. Read here about that. http://openhighschoolcourses.org/mod/book/tool/print/index.php?id=12503

Comment: is there another solution?

Comment: d://wamp/wp_bankers is my wamp directory path, now how can i use relative path?

Comment: Something like `/wp_bankers/css/` , Please see the video on the link. You will clearly understand it.

Comment: dear Shankar, when i access my wamp server on another computer every files are the address of with http:localhost/file name, but when i edit http://192.168.1.10/file name it can work.

Comment: basically i use WordPress and in wp_options tables i change my site address http://localhost/ into with my desire ip address and all gona work.

Comment: Thank, i see this but i did not know  before

Comment: Wow, so many people saying to edit the apache conf file elsewhere online, when this is the real solution and right in front of everyone's face...

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

As you are able to access it from the local computer that run the server by `http://localhost` you have two options to access it from your local area network LAN:

1. Using the local IP of the computer for example: `http://192.168.1.20`
2. Using the computer name for example: `http://computer1/`

To know your current IP:
 Start -> in search field write `cmd` and hit enter to open the command line -> in the command line write: ipconfig you will get something like that:

[image]

Your computer IP address is the value of IPv4 Address.

To know your computer name just right click on the computer icon in the start menu then choose properties to get this screen shot:

[image]

However, for computer name method you have to be sure that every computer in your LAN has a unique name.

#### Update

There are some routers firmware supports local DNS on the router, so you have not need to **edit the hosts files for every machine** in the network. For example that I already have, [dd-wrt](http://dd-wrt.com) firmware on Linksys WRT54G:

[image]

Comment: **+1** Nicely illustrated answer; indeed going to the IP within the address bar is the best method; there are a few more methods to making the web address more nicely such as amending the **hosts** file or adding a record within your local DNS server (if possible)

Comment: Very good idea about hosts file. However, it should need to assign a fixed IP address for the hoste server computer.

Comment: Hey, I never knew about using our device name for local networks to access the device!

Answer (score 5):

Mine wasn't working before when I tried using my computer's IP in the URL.
I found the reason to be the line in httpd.conf:

**ServerName localhost:80**

which I updated to be

**ServerName {My comp's IP}:80**

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 : Press window button + R at the same time which opens the run tool of Windows.
Step 2 : Write CMD, then press 'Enter' button. This operation opens CMD terminal.
Step 3 : Then write 'ipconfig' command
Step 4 : Then note your ipv4 Address : 192.168.x.x (From Wireless Lan Adapter Wi-Fi Header) (This Ip address is needed by other computers in the place of localhost in URL)
Step 5 : Go to phpmyadmin.conf file of hosting system(Where wamp is installed...File path ->   C:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf)
Step 6 : Replace this statement

```
<ifDefine APACHE24>
  Require local
</ifDefine>
<ifDefine !APACHE24>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
</ifDefine>
```

with

```
Require local
Require ip 192.168.0
```

Note : (If your Ip is something like 192.147.x.x) then you write 'Require 192.147.0' instead of 'require 192.168.0')

Step 7 : Restart your Wamp server
Step 8 : Enter the link 192.x.x.x/phpmyadmin in the url bar of your own system from which you want to access the hosting wamp server
Step 9 : End.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to access the wamp server from another LAN PC, as some of the answers have pointed out, you can use the `LAN IP` or `Computer-Name` in the URL, as long as VirtualHost's `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directive contains that `LAN IP` or `Computer-Name` (so Apache can return the correct website).

But if you need to use a domain-name, you'll have to edit every PC's `Hosts file` and update it with the correct domain-name to LAN IP address resolve (**and make sure that LAN IP is assigned each time to the correct device by the Router**).

Though there are much better solutions that will work for all devices (including Mac, Linux, mobile devices such as iPhones, Android phones, etc) if you have a WiFi Router that can either be flashed with one of the open firmwares or is already capable of `DNS Masquerading` as outlined here: [Accessing Websites on a Local Network (LAN) Web Server](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/accessing-websites-on-a-local-network-lan-web-server). "DNS Masquerading" (in this context) is basically using the WiFi Router's own "Hosts file" to do the domain-name to LAN IP resolve.

Comment: I simply clicked `put online` it is working, but I want allow only one project and prevent access to my other projects and most important PHPMYADMIN, how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

I couldn't connect event after doing all the above-mentioned steps. Then I uninstalled my current wampserver (3.0 version) and installed 2.5 version of wampserver. And it worked perfectly. You just need to click on 'Put Online' and you are done. Others can access your server by putting your ip address in the URL instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

1. stop the wamp server and open C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

replace

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

add

```
Require all granted
```

above the Directory closing tag.

2. Then turn off the **windows firewall** for **[domain, private,
   public]** networks in my case only **[private network]** works
3. Re-Start wamp server

Answer (score 0):

The first method that @Shankar Narayana explaind, didn't work for me, in fact I didn't find this option in wamp version 3.2.6 But I did something else that i did, and I tell it in brief here:

1. #### Network- figuring out your Computers IP address

> by "ipconfig" command in cmd.

2. #### Configuring WAMPServer virtual hosts

> open up the Apache menu and look for "httpd-vhosts.conf" option. choosing that option should open the vhosts configuration text file. set the configuration to allow Apache server to be accessible outside of localhost

```
       <VirtualHost *:80> ServerName  [Enter your Server Name here]
         ServerAlias [Enter your computer IP Address]
         DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/[Enter Website directory name here]"
         <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/[Enter Website directory name here]">
           Options  +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Require all granted 
         </Directory>
       </VirtualHost>
```

3. #### Allow inbound traffic through Windows firewall

   1. Search for “Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security”
   2. Open the Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security app.
   3. On the left panel right click on Inbound Rules.
   4. Select New Rule.

      While in the New Inbound Rule Wizard use the following options:

      - Rule Type:Port
      - Protocol and Port: TCP, specific local port: 80
      - Action: Allow the connection.
      - Profile: check all that applies. If you’re just hosting either Private or private check would suffice.
      - Name: whatever you like
4. #### Putting the Server online

> In my case I didn't set it but you can do it if needed. for more detail you can read in this article: https://jasondarkx2.com/how-to-put-wampserver-online/