# Cannot access wamp server 2.5 services on local network

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp

We have installed wampserver2.5 and set up the wampserver in my system, we can access through local system but cannot access trough my local network. The following error appears

[image: php server]

[image: phpmyadmin]

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access my Wamp Server on another Local Computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805093/how-to-access-my-wamp-server-on-another-local-computer)

Comment: Just a little point. **They are not errors** They are Apache telling you that you have tried to do something that you have not told it you want it to be allowed to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remember that WAMPServer comes configured assuming you are going to use it to develop php based websites locally on a single PC and therefore everything is setup so that the beginner will not get their system compromised by any Off-Box access.

If you want to allow other PC's on your network to access the site(s) you develop then you will have to make some changes to tell Apache that it is allowed to access connections from ip addresses that are not this PC's ip address's

First, if your network is closed i.e. not accessible from any other network or from the internet, you can simply use the wampmanager menus like so :-

```
wampmanager -> Put Online
```

This will chnage the httpd.conf file from

```
Require local
```

To

```
Require all granted
```

And restart Apache so it see's the change.

If you just want to open up your WAMPServer to your local network, or if you are in any way security conscious, it is better to edit the httpd.conf file manually again using the wampmanager menus to make sure you edit the correct file.

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

Find the line

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

And add this

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1
```

To allow any ip address on your local subnet i.e. any ip starting with 192.168.1

Or for a specific ip adderss only

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1.41
```

Now if you want to allow these other ip's access to phpMyAdmin then you need to edit this file: `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`

In here you will also see commands that tell Apache who is allowed to access this alias.
And change to look like this :-

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.1               <-- this line added
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanx @RiggsFolly , you made it so easy After such a hard search

Answer (score 0):

- Locate the file *httpd.conf*
  In my case the file is in *C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf*
- Then look for the line `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">`
- And then look for the line `Require local`, next write the following:
  `Require all granted`
- Restart your wampserver and you can browse the localhost on every device that stays connected in your local network.