# Cannot Access WAMP Server on Local Area Network Using PC name

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, lan

I've recently developed a web-based system for our company. I made it available for LAN computers using WAMP that I have installed in a PC that runs 24/7. It is accessible for LAN computers when the IP address of the server is used (e.g. 10.216.133.58:9999/tracker/index.php). I want to access it using the PC's name but the browser says that the page couldn't be found.

P.S. I changed the configuration in httpd.conf line which says "Listen 80" to "Listen 9999"

Comment: did you put it online

Comment: Yes, I did. I can access it using the IP address. @zan

Comment: Use a DNS to map the PC's name to the server IP address

Alternatively you can use Bind https://www.isc.org/downloads/

Comment: This link will help you .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805093/how-to-access-my-wamp-server-on-another-local-computer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Computer is in the Same LAN subnet.

To say things clear.

1. Say your computer and group of 9 other computer is connected to a Router/Switch which will hav intranet IP and assigns IP to all the internal 10 computer.
2. If you are trying to connect to you machine from some other computer that is connected to different router then when you type your address "10.216.133.58", the computer sends request to its Gateway which is the Router or Switch it is connected to. Since your computer is not connected to it, the router may not find your IP address as any valid IP address.
3. Contact your network administrator and check if your computer is having an IP that is publicly accessible within Intranet.