# I can't access my wamp server it's hostname from another computer

Tags: wampserver

I tried solving this for about days but I still can't find the error.

I added a hostname to my webserver and I can access it from the computer running Apache, but when I try to access the site from another computer it doesn't work. (Only using the hostname;the ip works fine)

I hope someone can help me with this!!!

Comment: What are your settings? How are you trying to access it from the other computer? Did you [follow this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805093/how-to-access-my-wamp-server-on-another-local-computer)?

Comment: Yes, I did it like that

Comment: Please explain how you _added a hostname to my webserver_ Do you mean you created a Virtual Host or something else?